# How do you know who you are supposed to defend on?

Tags: nba2k14

In MyCareer mode, sometimes a screen is shown showing who you are matched against (and must defend on). However, sometimes that player gets substituted out, or when you enter the game, there's no such hint.

Is there a way to access this information from some menu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some blue arrows on the ring under your player pointing to an opponent player, and also arrows from that player pointing to you. This is apparently the player you're matched with and must defend on.

However, this information is real time, and can change during a possession, if your teammates decide to switch. As you have no clue when this happens (as opposed to real basketball where players talk to each other), other than the arrows changing player, you can try preventing this by defending very close to your opponent.